# PostgreSQL: jdbc, functions and autocommit

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I've got a PL/pgSQL function and I'm connecting to Postgres 12.x using Scala library called doobie which uses JDBC underneath. I'd like to understand if the whole call to the function will be treated as a single transaction? I've got default setting of autocommit.

The call to the function is simply:

`select * from next_work_item();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions in PostgreSQL are always running in a single transaction, no matter what.